# How can I solve the React void element tag error?

Tags: reactjs

I haven't found any solution so I hope you guys can help me.

So I'm trying to follow a a tutorial but now I got stuck because I'm getting [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BekSX.png)

I've already been debugging and found out it was because of some void elements I have calling other components.

```
<Grid container justify="space-between" alignItems="stretch" spacing = {3}>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={7}>
                        <Posts />             //this one
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xs={12} sm={7}>
                        <Form />              //and this one
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
```

How can I solve this? Is there any way to ignore the error? The guy from the tutorial doesn't seem to have this kind of problem.

If I comment those tags, it starts working again without that error, so I don't get why this is happening.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: at some component you have something like <hr>irregular content for hr<hr/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have an `hr` tag with content inside like `<hr>...</hr>`, but the `hr` tag should only be used as `<hr />` without any content since it is a "void element tag". Most likely this `hr` tag is somewhere inside `Posts` or `Form`, or you maybe meant to use `h4` instead? Posting more of the code in `Posts` or `Form` would also help find the issue.